# C# MVC application HTTP Post Request Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is making a post request from a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateFood(FoodItemVM vm)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("http://localhost:7173");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json");

    var food = service.CreateFoodItem(vm);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/foodItems", food);

    return View(vm);
}
```

to an API:

```
// POST: api/FoodItems
// To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<FoodItem>> PostFoodItem(FoodItem foodItem)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.FoodItems.Add(foodItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var DTO = new FoodItemDTO()
                  {
                      FoodItemId = foodItem.FoodItemId,
                      Title = foodItem.Title,
                      Description = foodItem.Description,
                      isVegan = foodItem.IsVegan,
                      Price = foodItem.UnitPrice
                  };

    return CreatedAtAction("GetFoodItem", new { id = foodItem.FoodItemId }, DTO);
}
```

Upon creating an item I get this error:

[image]

I have tried turning off all firewalls, and also trying on a different machine with no luck.

Any ideas of potential solutions, or point me in the right direction to fixing this issue, thank you in advance

Comment: It seems you own the API code. When start the API, can you access it using an url in your browser? On what localhost port? Can you set a breakpoint in an anonymous GET call and confirm that you hit the code? I would make sure that the API is reachable first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes i own the APi, I can access it through the browser url and items are GET and POST as expected, the problem arises when I attempt to access the POST method through a HTTP client in a  controller in my MVC application. I have just put in a break point as suggested and the response is null. I should clarify that the GET method works as expected through the aforementioned process.

Comment: Ok, you can try making a GET request to a known host like `http://www.google.com`. You can try getting rid of the `BaseAddress` and use an absolute URL in `PostAsJsonAsync`. You could also try capital case `http://localhost:7173/api/FoodItem`. I see nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is now working as expected, if your interested in the fix: i was missing an 's' from HTTP'S'.